# Returning structures in functions results in incompatible declaration

Tags: c++, struct

So, i have two files `interpretor.h` and `interpretor.cpp`.
I want to have a method to return a struct but it is always saying that i cannot convert to to incomplete class or declaration is incompatible.
Could someone help me?
I will put some code here:

interpretor.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "calc3.h"

class interpretor
{
public:
    interpretor(nodeType* STprogram);

private:
    /* for passing informations */
    struct returner {
        union
        {
            int integer;
            float real;
        };

        int type;
    };
    
    struct returner test();
};
```

and interpretor.cpp

```
#include "interpretor.h"

// ...

struct returner interpretor::test() {
    returner p;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: I edited the question and the title to make the question more clear for future readers. If you don't agree with some changes feel free to roll them back!

Answer (score 4):

The error come from `struct returner` declaring a new forward declared type when it is not found. In your case, the type is not found so it create a new one, hence you incompatible declaration error. If you dropped the `struct` in front of the `returner`, it would show a more helpful error:

> ```
> <source>:7:1: error: 'returner' does not name a type
>     7 | returner interpretor::test() {}
>       | ^~~
> ```

When using a member type of a class, you must use the qualified name of the type:

```
interpretor::returner interpretor::test() {
    returner p;
    return p;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use trailing return types which makes it easier for the compiler to find the names:

```
auto interpretor::test() -> returner {
    returner p;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: many thanks, it helped a lot! now i think is working :)

Answer (score 1):

The structure `returner` is declared inside the class `interpretor`, so the name of the class should be added outside `class { }` and `{ }` in member function definitions.

```
struct interpretor::returner interpretor::test() {
    returner p;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: many thanks, it helped a lot! now i think is working :)